# Regrid a GRIB2 file and convert to netCDF

Tags: netcdf, grib-2, wgrib2

I have a GRIB2 file on a Gaussian grid. I'd like to convert it to a netCDF file with to an equally-spaced 0.5-degree grid. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done with with the [wgrib2 utility](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/). However, the version of wgrib2 that is included in some Linux distributions does not have the ability to interpolate, so you may need to compile it yourself.

Once you have a suitable version of wgrib2, you can regrid a file to a half-degree grid as follows:

```
wgrib2 data.grb2 -new_grid latlon -179.75:720:0.5 -89.75:360:0.5 data_halfdeg.grb2
```

Then, you can convert the regridded file to netCDF with

```
wgrib2 data_halfdeg.grb -netcdf data_halfdeg.nc
```

The dimensions in the netCDF file will be named "latitude" and "longitude". If your application is anticipating "lat" and "lon", you can rename these with the [NetCDF operators](https://github.com/nco/nco):

```
ncrename -dlatitude,lat -dlongitude,lon \
         -vlatitude,lat -vlongitude,lon data_halfdeg.nc
```

where the `-d` and `-v` flags are used to rename the dimensions and their associated coordinate variables.